# Error 'An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle-11g

Tengo las siguientes sentencias para Modificar un objeto del Entity Framework que está enlazado a una base de datos de oracle:

```
        using (BASEntities context = new BASEntities())
            {
        //Este método comprueba que exista en caso de existir modificar
        string RespuestaValidacion = ExisteConcepto(context, ConceptoTo);
             CONCEPTO objConceptoBasico = new  CONCEPTO
               {
                  CODIGOCTO = ConceptoTo.CodigoConcepto,
                  CODIGOENTIDAD = ConceptoTo.CodigoEntidad,
                   demas codigo..... 
                };

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RespuestaValidacion))
                {
                    context.CONCEPTO.Add(objConceptoBasico);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else 
                {
                  context.CONCEPTO.Attach(objConceptoBasico);
                 context.CONCEPTO.System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified(objConceptoBasico);
                  context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

el método para Buscar si existe el registro es el siguiente:

```
   private string ExisteConcepto(BASEntities context, ConceptoTO ConceptoTo)
    {
        try
        {
            var qRegistro = context.SMT_CONCEPTOBASICO.Where(k => 
                                    k.CODIGONEG == ConceptoTo.CodigoNegocio
                                    && k.CODIGOCTO == ConceptoTo.CodigoConcepto
                                    && k.IDAPLICACION == ConceptoTo.IdAplicacion
                                    demas codigo......).FirstOrDefault();                    


            return qRegistro == null ? "" : qRegistro.ESTADO;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Y sale el mencionado error:

> Error 'An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.'

*realice el cambio de entity 5 a entity 6*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese es un error causado por las validaciones de EF.

Para solucionarlo puedes hacer algo como:

```
try
{
  context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

  context.CONCEPTO.Attach(objConceptoBasico);
  context.Entry(objConceptoBasico).State = EntityState.Deleted;
  context.SaveChanges();
}
finally
{
  context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
}
```

================== EDICIÓN ======================

El error ocurre porque estas intentando agregar una entidad que ya ha sido agregada de forma implícita al realizar el `FirstOrDefault` en el método: `ExisteConcepto`.

Conosco 2 formas para solucionar el mismo:

1. Puedes en el método: `ExisteConcepto` retornar el objeto en vez de string y al objeto (si existe) cambiarles las propiedades de forma manual o con AupoMapper (por ejemplo).

Algo como:

```
private string ExisteConcepto(BASEntities context, ConceptoTO ConceptoTo)
    {
        try
        {
            return context.SMT_CONCEPTOBASICO.Where(k => 
                                    k.CODIGONEG == ConceptoTo.CodigoNegocio
                                    && k.CODIGOCTO == ConceptoTo.CodigoConcepto
                                    && k.IDAPLICACION == ConceptoTo.IdAplicacion
                                    demas codigo......).FirstOrDefault();                    
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Luego en tu método principal:

```
...
CONCEPTO concepto = ExisteConcepto(context, ConceptoTo);

if(concepto == null) concepto = new CONCEPTO();
...
```

Luego proceder a cambiar las propiedades si el concepto existe o a agregarlas si es nuevo:

```
concepto.CODIGOCTO = ConceptoTo.CodigoConcepto;
...
```

Esta es la forma que recomiendo de forma personal.

2. La segunda forma es hacer un `Count` en vez de un `FirstOrDefault` en el método: `ExisteConcepto` entonces retornaras la cantidad de elementos que coinciden con los criterios del where y en el método principal solo evaluaras en vez de: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(RespuestaValidacion)` algo como: `RespuestaValidacion == 0`

Comment: ya sale un error diferente "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

Comment: @ger eso ocurre porque en alguna parte lo estas agregando el objeto con `Attach` o realizando un "get" de ese objeto y por tal razón se esta agregando mas de una vez al  ObjectStateManager.

Si puedes agregar el código completo podré evaluar mejor.

Comment: voy agregar el metodo que me consulta si existe y parte donde creo el objeto para ingresarlo o modificarlo en el modelo

Comment: @ger acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, esto funciona tanto para el Update como para el Delete.